How to create an array with unique elements in the order of their first occurrence in the original array?
The task was to create a second array that contains each number only once. However, the order should correspond to that of the first occurrence in the original array. The solution array is output in the main program.
I have programmed this code:
public static int[] sortSecArr (int[] arr){
   int dumpArr[] = new int[arr.length];
   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
         if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
            dumpArr[i] = arr[i] ;
         }
      }     
   }
   return dumpArr;
}

I have tried to make it in two for loops, then the arr[i] is compared to the arr[j] and when it is not the same then it should get into the dumpArr.
I know something is wrong, but don't have any idea what needs to be changed in this code.

To bad you can't just use: int[] newArray = Arrays.stream(originalArray).distinct().toArray();.

If you can use dynamic array you can do this(I wrote it in python, but you can use e.g java ArrayList:
def solve(a: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    answer = []
    for number in a:
        if number not in answer:
            answer.append(number)
    return answer

assert solve([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1]) == [1, 2, 5, 6, 3]
assert solve([]) == []
assert solve([1, 2, 3]) == [1, 2, 3]
assert solve([1, 1, 1]) == [1]
assert solve([1, 2, 1, 2]) == [1, 2]

in java function signature will be:
public static ArrayList<Integer> solve(int[] arr);


If you need to return int[] you need to count how many unique elements in input array. You can do this with set or hashmap

If you don't allowed to use maps, sets etc, you can:

Allocate array of zeros with length of input
Use i to iterate through arr, j to iterate through new arr
Iter through arr:

int new_arr[] = new int[arr.length()];
int j_max;
while (i < arr.length()){
    if arr[i] not in new_arr then
        new_arr[j++] = arr[i++]
        j_max = j
    else
        i++
}

This is pseudocode

You need to return slice of new_arr from 0 to j_max-1

return Arrays.copyOfRange(new_arr, 0, j_max-1);


ok thank you i will try too write it in java code

Here is another solution:
public static int[] sortSecArr (int[] arr){
   int dumpArr[] = new int[arr.length];
   int n = 0;
   for(int val: arr){
       int j = 0;
       while (j < n && val > dumpArr[j]) {
           ++j;
       }
       if (j == n) {
           dumpArr[n++] = val;
       } else if (val < dumpArr[j]) {
           while (j < n) {
               int x = dumpArr[j];
               dumpArr[j] = val;
               val = x;
               ++j;
           }
           dumpArr[n++] = val;
       }
   }
   // Resize result
   int[] result = new int[n];
   for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
       result[j] = dumpArr[j];
   }
   return result;
}

